# How to disable Android system keyboard in app

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I have an android app with a webview and some other android element like buttons or surfaceviews.
Noone of them requires a keyboard.

The webview has it's own keyboard so i dont want the android keyboard to pop up.

The only solution i found was to disable focus.

`((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.browserLayout)).setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);`

Because of blocking focus onFocus events in webview stopped working.
Is there any other solution to disable the keyboard in the app.

Thanks
Best Regards

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);      
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)   
{  
    edittext.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);  
    edittext.setTextIsSelectable(true);  
}
```

Comment: this will only work for edittext and has to be assigned to every edittextl, the keyboard will always be shown webview when clicking into an input